# Bash searching for words in file with same characters

Tags: string, bash, file, cpu-word

Is it possible to write the script `script.sh`, using BASH that

- The argument is a string of characters and the output is all possible words 
  from these characters and The script searches for words in the file besede.txt in this case only two words

```
$script.sh jugrot
jogurt
rojgut
```

does somebody know what is wrong and why it doesn't want to add all permutations into a table

```
#!/bin/bash

permutation() {
  array=()
  local items="$1"
  local out="$2"
  local i
  [[ "$items" == "" ]] && array[$i]+=$out && return
  for (( i=0; i<${#items}; i++ )) ; do
    permutation "${items:0:i}${items:i+1}" "$out${items:i:1}"
  done
  }

permutation $1

for i in "${array[$i]}"
do 
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Yes.  It is possible.  It could help, though, if you demonstrate how you've tried to solve this problem and where you hit a roadblock.

Comment: i know how to read file, but i don't know how to then check if they include all the characters and if the length is the same?

Comment: Well, dummy solution would be: create a list of all possible combinations of letters of the word and then grep for each combination inside the "besede.txt" word list.

Comment: thanks mate i'll try, i'm really a total beginer at programing and at bash